# The .setNumber() wont update the small number on Android Notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I'm trying to handle notifications that comes from server, I use

`public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {` not an Activity.

When the notification comes I want to update the notification number. But it doesn't work.

Here is the full code:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static int numMessages = 0;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.

                Log.i("SMS", "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.getString("default"));
                Log.i("SMS", "Received: " + extras.getString("default"));
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
       // numMessages = 0;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, Main.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setTicker("Coople go go go")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("New Coople discount")
                        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg).setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setNumber(++numMessages);



      //  mNotificationManager.setContentText("New")


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you see the number but with a wrong value, or is the number not displayed at all?

Comment: @Eran i see nothing. No number is appear. When i do .setNumber(2); the number is appear. but with .setNumber(++numMessages); nothing is appear

Comment: Perhaps `numMessages` doesn't contain what you think it does. If you are passing `0`, that may be the reason nothing is displayed. You get the value from a global variable, but I'm not sure what happens to that variable when the app is not running. Perhaps you should store that number in shared preferences and load it from there.

Comment: I receive notification number as a badge in the notification payload. I parse it to integer but number doesn't show up in the device. I also tried setting number statically but in this case, it works as expected.